# How to properly implement protocols and delegates between different view controllers in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, delegates, viewcontroller

So I am new to protocols and delegate. However I tried to use one in my project after learning about it. I'm not sure if I did anything wrong. But I can't update the label.

---

```
import UIKit

class CountryVC: UIViewController {
    //MARK:-Properties   
    let deathLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "I am Death"
        return label
    }()
    let recoveredLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()
    let infectedLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(deathsView)
        view.addSubview(infectedView)
        view.addSubview(recoveredView)

        deathsView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 100, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20, height: 100)
        deathsView.addSubview(deathLabel)
        deathLabel.anchor()
        deathLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: deathsView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        deathLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: deathsView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        infectedView.anchor(top: deathsView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20, height: 100)
        deathsView.addSubview(infectedLabel)
        infectedLabel.anchor()
        infectedLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infectedView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        infectedLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infectedView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true       
        recoveredView.anchor(top: infectedView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20, height: 100)
        recoveredView.addSubview(recoveredLabel)
        recoveredLabel.anchor()
        recoveredLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: recoveredView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        recoveredLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: recoveredView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

---

```
extension CountryVC: UpdateCountry {
    func update(allCases: Int, recovered: Int, deaths: Int) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.deathLabel.text = String(deaths)
            self.recoveredLabel.text = String(recovered)
            self.infectedLabel.text = String(allCases)
        }
        print (String(deaths))
        print(String(recovered))
        print(String(allCases))
    }
}
```

---

I can see the data getting passed as I can print the datas. I called the update function in my other table view controller to get the data like this.

---

```
class CountryTableControllerTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    //MARK:- Properties
    var delegate: UpdateCountry!
    //MARK:- Initialization
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = CountryVC()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
        self.navigationItem.title = "Select Your Country"
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { 1 }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { countries.count }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let urlCountry = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries/\(countries[indexPath.row])"
        let acturalUrl = urlCountry.lowercased()
        guard let url = URL(string: acturalUrl) else { return }
        let controler = CountryVC()
        controler.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(controler, animated: true, completion: nil)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do {
                let allCases = try JSONDecoder().decode(CountryCases.self, from: data)
                self.delegate.update(allCases: allCases.cases, recovered: allCases.recovered, deaths: allCases.deaths)  
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()     
    }
}
```

The controller is presented with the data but the label isn't updated in the countryVC.

Comment: You need to show your CountryVC class, your updateCountry protocol and tableview code. Make sure to set its delegate. Note that it is Swift naming convention to name your protocols starting with an uppercase letter `UpdateCountry`

Comment: Note that your code is asynchronous. You should present you CountryVC controler before decoding your json in your completion handler. Presenting it right after calling resume it won't wait your asynchronous request to complete.

Comment: Why the values in label in set `DispatchQueue`

Comment: Values in label is set in main thread as updating UI elements is always done in the main queue.

Comment: @LeoDabus I still can't see the updates in the label even after doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create your protocol as follow:

```
protocol CountryViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func updateLabels(_ controller: CountryViewController, country: String, allCases: Int, recovered: Int, deaths: Int)
}
```

---

Then in your CountryViewController:

```
class CountryViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: CountryViewControllerDelegate?
    // code ...
}
```

---

```
extension CountryViewController: CountryViewControllerDelegate {
    func updateLabels(_ controller: CountryViewController, country: String,  allCases: Int, recovered: Int, deaths: Int) {
        print("CountryViewController:", #function)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            // update your labels in the main thread 
            // self.deathLabel.text = String(deaths)
            // self.recoveredLabel.text = String(recovered)
            // self.infectedLabel.text = String(allCases)

            print("Country:", country)
            print("deaths:", deaths)
            print("recovered:", recovered)
            print("infected:", allCases)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Finally in your CountryTableViewController:

```
class CountryTableViewController: UITableViewController, CountryViewControllerDelegate { 

    weak var delegate: CountryViewControllerDelegate?
    // code ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = "Select Your Country"
        delegate = self
    }

    // code ...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let country = countries[indexPath.row]
        let string = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries/\(country.lowercased())"
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CountryViewController") as! CountryViewController
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
        controller.title = country
        let countryNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        countryNavigationController.viewControllers = [controller]
        self.present(countryNavigationController, animated: true)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error  in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8), string == "Country not found"  {
                self.updateLabels(controller, country: country, allCases: 0, recovered: 0, deaths: 0)
                return
            }
            do {
                let allCases = try JSONDecoder().decode(CountryCases.self, from: data)
                self.updateLabels(controller, country: country, allCases: allCases.cases, recovered: allCases.recovered, deaths: allCases.deaths)
            } catch {
                print("JSON error:", error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    func updateLabels(_ controller: CountryViewController, country: String, allCases: Int, recovered: Int, deaths: Int) {
        print("CountryTableViewController:", #function)
        controller.updateLabels(controller, country: country, allCases: allCases, recovered: recovered, deaths: deaths)
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sh3hqjh5mn4wb61/Corona%20Virus.zip?dl=1)