# pass text from selected tableView cell.row to fill textbox xcode

Tags: ios, swift, textview, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableView that allows users to make multiple selections from an array of data,

[image: image1]

When the user clicks done, I would like the selected text to be then transferred over to another tableViews textView

[image: image2]

Is there a way to transfer over the selected text and have the text separated by a , ?

I am coding programmatically.

```
    var checked = [Int]()
var items = [String]()
var selectedItems = [String]()

     @objc func done() {
    
          let hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)
          hud.textLabel.text = "Saving!"
          hud.show(in: view)
          dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
          hud.dismiss()
    
    let aCell = aboutCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    aCell.textField3.text = selectedItems.joined(separator: ",")
    
}
 
    
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark {
        
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
        
    } else {
        
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
        
         if selectedItems.contains(items[indexPath.row]) {
            selectedItems.remove(at: selectedItems.firstIndex(of: items[indexPath.row])!)
            } else {
            selectedItems.append(items[indexPath.row])
            }
        checked.append(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

Comment: To John array of string in to one string use Johned func: array.joined(separator: ","). For transfer over the selected text, there are many way to transfer data over screen, just search for it. good luck

Comment: @goat_herd how can I save the selected rows, and then separate them in the next view? maybe I should have gone step by step in my question.

Comment: you have the indexPath of selected row right?, from indexPath you can get the selected data from your data right ?

Comment: @goat_herd I have updated my question, All I have up to now is how to check the the selected rows.

Comment: I see you have checked array to save checked indexPath right ?

Comment: @goat_herd it just selects the text, it doesnt pass that text to the next view controller. Once I hit done, the tableView will dismiss and the checkmarks disappear.

Comment: see the answer of Sudan suwal :)

Comment: @zachwilcox can you edit your post. There is two  didSelectRowAt methods.

Comment: @LeoDabus edited

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding to the question, these are my thoughts:

**1. First setup necessary variables**

```
var items = [String]() // data to display in tableview

var selectedItems = [String]() // here all the selected datas are stored
```

**2. Store the selected items data from the *didSelectRowAt* delegate method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if selectedItems.contains(items[indexPath.row]) { //check if the selected already contains the items and if contains remove it
            selectedItems.remove(at: selectedItems.firstIndex(of: items[indexPath.row])!)
        } else { // append the required items
            selectedItems.append(items[indexPath.row])
        }
       // ..... other codes here
        
    }
```

**3. on done button**

```
let requiredText = selectedItems.joined(separator: ",")
// pass this data through delegate method
```

Comment: I have updated the code in my question to try and reflect your suggestions, I am receiving the following error Fatal error: Index out of range:  on   if selectedItems.contains(items[indexPath.row]) {.

Comment: I received that error when I tried to click on a row and display a check mark.

Comment: checked.remove(at: selectedItems.firstIndex(of: items[indexPath.row])!) this line is error I guess
I think it should be selectedItems.remove(at: selectedItems.firstIndex(of: items[indexPath.row])!)

Comment: I still receive the error message! I tried to delete the checked.append(indexPath.row) or rearrange the lines of code but it still shows. Im sorry!

Comment: bro you are still using checked.remove ?? 
you appended your data in selectedItems .. just remove the checked variable completely if there is already selectedItems variable

Comment: Oh no im sorry I changed that to selectedItems

Comment: @LeoDabus it is a tableView!

Comment: @LeoDabus could you possibly leave an answer so we don't flood sudans inbox with notifications?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220897/discussion-between-sudan-suwal-and-zach-wilcox).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create an array for the selected items. You can simply call tableview method [`selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614875-selectrow) when selecting a row and when you need to get the selected rows just call tableview instance property [`indexPathsForSelectedRows`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows). Then you just need to join the selected rows with a comma and use the resulting string in your textview or textfield. Don't forget to implement [`didDeselectRowAt`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614916-tableview) item method as well to [`deselectRow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614989-deselectrow).

---

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var items: [String] = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }
    func done() {
        if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            // note that this will preserve the order that the rows where selected. Just sort the indexPaths if you need it sorted. 
            let string = indexPaths.map { items[$0.row] }.joined(separator: ",")
            print(string)
            
            // your code
        }
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCellID", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = cell.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }

}
```

---

Comment: would I still be adding the checkmarks and then when I press done, it knows which rows were selected and are ready to pass forward?

Comment: Thanks for your help! With using your code, I can only select 1 indexPath at a time and when I press done I get Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range on let string =

Comment: I have added the viewDidLoad method as well `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true` https://www.dropbox.com/s/msfbb8bvtjqtv8g/TableView%20Sample.zip?dl=1

Comment: I did! It successfully prints in the console! But now I am trying to figure out the origianl question which is how to get the selected text to be presented inside of the textView of the origianl controller.

Comment: So you don't know how to pass the string from one controller to another?

Comment: Exactly! I understand I have to transfer data with a delegate method but I am looking this up

Comment: the delegate is the best way to go

Comment: I understand that now I am trying to figure out how :0

Comment: this might help. It is not so easy but once you understand how it works you will always use it when coding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60808627/how-to-properly-implement-protocols-and-delegates-between-different-view-control/60840590#60840590