# Swift: How to pass data when popping view controller

Tags: ios, swift, navigationcontroller, popviewcontroller

I want to pass data from childVC to parentVC when popping view controller.

> ChildViewController {    /*processing data*/    //get data value
> value = 123    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:
> true) }
>
> ParentViewController {    //use the value from child vc(value 123) }

How can i pass the data back to use it in ParentViewController?

Comment: you can use a segue https://stackoverflow.com/a/35314768/2303865, post a  notification https://stackoverflow.com/a/30541063/2303865 or use a delegate https://stackoverflow.com/a/60840590/2303865

Answer (score 1):

You can use a segue, and prepare for the segue before popping to the new view controller.

**In VC1**

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "toVC2", sender: self)

let dataInVC1 = "wow"

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toVC2" {
        let vc = segue.destination as SecondViewController
         vc?.someData = dataInVC1
}
```

**In VC2**

```
var someData: String?
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a callback closure property on the child. Set it from the parent when setting up the child view controller. When the child is done, check if callback is != nil (if optional) and if so, call it before popping.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your custom handler for completion after you pop. Here is an example:

```
extension UINavigationController {

func popViewControllerWithHandler(animated:Bool = true, completion: @escaping ()->()) {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)
    self.popViewController(animated: animated)
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

}